# Facebook Graph API cannot UPDATE the fields about URL link such as name, caption, description or picture after published

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build A/B testing tool for Facebook page post.
And then I need to update the post's field about URL link like name (article's title), caption, description or picture (article's thumbnail).

So I have been making sure whether it can be possible or not by using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). But it seams impossible to update the fields after published.

Of course, I checked [Facebook official Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post). But the reference does not clearly explain it is impossible.
I've got permission of `user_posts`, `publish_actions` and `publish_pages` to make a POST Method request.

Please tell me whether it's possible or not. If possible, tell me the way.

Comment: _“But the reference does not clearly explain it is impossible”_ – what part of _“An app can update a post if it published it”_ and _“You can update the fields listed in the Publishing sections of the /{user-id}/feed, /{page-id}/feed, /{event-id}/feed, or /{group-id}/feed edges”_ is unclear to you?

Answer (score 1):

As @CBroe stated, it's clearly pointed out in the docs what is possible concerning updating, and how.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post#updating